# When changing my potentially offensive email name using a more professional naming standard, do I have to justify it to my professional contacts?

Tags: email

When I first made my professional facing email, I had made some blunders in the naming and had planned to change it when possible. The format of the email in question was "[Verb][Numbers][Verb]@[Domain].com" and I plan to change it to the typical "[FirstName][LastName]@[Domain].com".

To add to my issue, I recently learned that my email name can be interpreted as offensive from the cultural standpoint of my employers and peers. To explain, the email name's numbers have an extreme political connotation; the numbers are seen favorably in the culture I was raised in, so I did not realize the connotation until I stumbled upon it.

I plan to gradually migrate the accounts I registered with this old email to my new one. However, how do I discuss my email change with my former colleagues? I have an employer and references who contact me through this old email.

- Do I need to justify this email change to them?
- Do I have to apologize or explain for any perceived association with an extreme political party?

Comment: Hi X, my new email is: email@here.com. Why more than that?

Comment: would you feel a similar need to justify changing mailing address or phone number?

Comment: Presumably, I should not assume people who already have a good opinion of me should have anything against me if all I say is my new email is xyz@abc.com, correct?

Comment: I've managed IT for over 30 years and never seen a company that would have allowed you to choose an email address like that in the first place.

Comment: Why not set a forward, in addition?

Comment: You just do it.  No explanation, just state "*My new email address is blah@blah.blah".

Comment: @Steve work for a small enough company or be self-employed and anything goes.

Answer (score 3):

When it was framed as something similar to a change in physical address or phone number, it just makes sense to just say the email is being changed without any more explanation.

I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with many teenagers who, when we got to know each other, had email addresses like `sk8erboy@gmail.com` or `little.blonde.girl.98@yahoo.com`. My advice to them was, "get professional!"

You should do the same. Your email address is your public face. Get a good one based on your name, and don't look back.

If you're on a company email system, get the administrator to rig your old address as an alias for the new one. And never send out another message, or reply to a message, under the old name again. It will fade away soon enough.